# ftp download cause program to become unresponsive untill download complete

Tags: python, download, ftp, qthread

My program becomes unresponsive when downloading files from ftp. I'm looking at qthread but confused on how to use it.

```
def Download(self):

    #self.startbutton1.destroy()

    userprofile = environ['USERPROFILE']
    tempfile = environ['TEMP']

    ftp = FTP('ftpsite')
    ftp.login(user='username', passwd = 'PWhere')
    ftp.nlst()

    ftp.cwd(self.directoryftp)

    #Download all file in directory
    filenames = ftp.nlst()
    print filenames

    if not os.path.exists(tempfile + "\\PythonEXE\'s"):
        os.makedirs(tempfile + "\\PythonEXE\'s")

    for filename in filenames:
        local_filename = os.path.join(tempfile + "\\PythonEXE\'s", filename)
        file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
    file.close()
```

Comment: What UI framework are you using? PyQt?

Comment: Tkinter is what I use for GUI